# Настройка подключения заголовков по умолчанию

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, include

Есть ли возможность настроить подключение часто используемых заголовков при создании нового проекта Visual Studio 2017 по умолчанию? Благодарю за ответ или ссылку на ответ

Comment: Что подразумевается под "часто используемых заголовков"? Подключение куда? В каждый файл исходного кода следует явно включать все требующиеся ему заголовочные файлы. Непонятно, при чем тут создание нового проекта.

Comment: Создайте проект с нужными инклюдами. Главное меню: Project > Export Template. Теперь можете использовать этот шаблон.